# Compilation error in declaration of method which accepts input as block with variable number of arguments

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-blocks, variadic-functions

When I am declaring a method like this:

```
- (void)doAnythingWithThisBlock:(void(^)(NSString *, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION))AnythingBlock;
```

It is giving compilation error:

```
Expected ')'
```

but when I am declaring it like this:

```
- (void)doAnythingWithThisBlock:(void(^)(NSString *, ...))AnythingBlock;
```

It compiles fine and works as expected

Cannot we use - NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION while declaring a method which accepts input as block with variable number of arguments?

I am trying it in XCode 4.2

Comment: +1 have u resolved this issue ?

Comment: hey.. I need to check back.. this I asked a long time back..

Comment: anyways did you check .. NSString.h.. method declaration of - (instancetype)initWithFormat:(NSString *)format.. it uses NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2); .. may be you want to have a look on it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I guess NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION is only for method declarations [1](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html)

However you can try to typedef your block to certain type and pass it as an argument: may be clang will eat it then?